# VBA Excel WorksheetFunction.Rank issue

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA so please go easy on me.

I have a list of numbers 120 000 rows long that I want to rank in increments of 12 - meaning that the first 12 numbers should be ranked from 1 to 12, the following 12 numbers from 1 to 12 and so on.

I know how to do this in Excel, one increment at a time, using the Rank function, but since it would take me forever to do manually I decided to try to code a macro to do it for me.

This is as far as I've come.

```
Sub Rank()

    Range("H1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Rank(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(12, 1))
    Range("H200000").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(11, 0)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

I've done multiple iterations trying to figure out where I'm going wrong but I'm currently stuck. I'm sure there's an easy way to figure this out but I just don't have the skills to do it without help, so any aid would be much obliged.

Comment: please give some details as to how are your "numbers" scattered along a columns (groups of twelve cells separated by blank cells, consecutive, other...), which column they belong to and which column should hold their rank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues here:

ActiveCell is a read-only property. You move it by using .Activate rather than setting ActiveCell.

Rank takes three arguments: a cell (or value) as the lookup value, a range to find the rank within, and a value to set ascending or descending rank. You have passed it three cells.

The final lines of code, which are the only ones which have an effect on the spreadsheet, copy the final item in column H down for another 12 cells. I don't think this is quite the effect you were looking for...

The following assumes that your data starts in H2, and places the rank within each block of 12 in column I. Is this more what you were looking for?

```
Sub Rank()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To 10000
        For j = 1 To 12
            Cells((i - 1) * 12 + (j + 1), 9).Value = WorksheetFunction.Rank(Cells((i - 1) * 12 + (j + 1), 8), Range(Cells((i - 1) * 12 + 2, 8), Cells((i - 1) * 12 + 13, 8)), 1)
        Next j
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It worked a treat, with only one hiccup - I need to reverse the rank order. Now the lowest number gets the lowest rank whereas I would like for it to be so that the highest number gets the lowest rank. Any ideas?

Comment: Use 0 rather than 1 at the end of the function - as I mentioned, the third parameter that you pass to Rank determines the order.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks again!